# Create bootstrap columns with Laravel and foreach

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I want the items of my $favs object to be grouped in 4 columns for each row

```
<div class="row row justify-content-center">
                          <div class="col-9">
                              <div class="row">
                                 @foreach ($favs->items as $fav)
                                  <ul class="col-sm-3 list-unstyled">
                                    <li class="subcat-li"><a href="{{ route('web.custom_url',$fav->seo->slug ) }}">{{ $fav->name }}</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                                 @endforeach
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

I want it to look like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked Chunk() : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-chunk

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="row">
        @foreach($favs->items as $fav)
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="{{ route('web.custom_url',$fav->seo->slug ) }}">{{ $fav->name }}</a>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```